# MySQL shutting down unexpectedly every 24 hours on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

For the past few days, my three servers have been experiencing the same problem almost at the same time, about every 24 hours.

I haven't changed anything in the code using MySQL or ubuntu configuration for months.

What I can see in the error logs (/var/log/mysql/error.log) is that apparently MySQL stops by itself for no reason:

```
2022-02-10T06:48:17.246813Z 0 [Note] Giving 10 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2022-02-10T06:48:17.246853Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2022-02-10T06:48:19.246990Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 10 remaining clients
2022-02-10T06:48:19.247028Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 7  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249583Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 10  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249613Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249628Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 51  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249641Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249654Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249667Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 4  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249680Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 5  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249693Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 6  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249705Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 9  user: 'root'

2022-02-10T06:48:19.249723Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2022-02-10T06:48:19.252212Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254111Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254125Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254130Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254135Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254139Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254168Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254173Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254180Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254184Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254188Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254191Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254195Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254198Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254202Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254206Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254209Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254213Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254216Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254220Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254223Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254227Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254230Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254234Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254237Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254241Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254244Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254248Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254251Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254255Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254258Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254262Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254265Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254269Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254272Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254276Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254279Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254295Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254299Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254402Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2022-02-10T06:48:19.254552Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-02-10T06:48:19.354843Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-10T06:48:19.356501Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220210  6:48:19
2022-02-10T06:48:20.819810Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 36134591308
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820204Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820215Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820222Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820225Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2022-02-10T06:48:20.820358Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2022-02-10T06:48:20.821311Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2022-02-10T06:48:21.370898Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-02-10T06:48:21.372832Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 8693 ...
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377512Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377538Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377543Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377547Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-10T06:48:21.377915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-02-10T06:48:21.379635Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-02-10T06:48:21.447914Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-10T06:48:21.463713Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-02-10T06:48:21.484266Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2022-02-10T06:48:21.484292Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 0 undo tablespaces made active
2022-02-10T06:48:21.484511Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.520917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-02-10T06:48:21.521030Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-02-10T06:48:21.552476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.552668Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: The parameter innodb_undo_logs is deprecated and may be removed in future releases. Please use innodb_rollback_segments instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-undo-logs.html
2022-02-10T06:48:21.553292Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 redo rollback segment(s) found. 1 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.553304Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.553598Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-02-10T06:48:21.603836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.37 started; log sequence number 36134591308
2022-02-10T06:48:21.604219Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.604678Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-10T06:48:21.606857Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist
2022-02-10T06:48:21.606890Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.608219Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.608233Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.608238Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.608241Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.611484Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.611520Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.614815Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.615451Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.615470Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2022-02-10T06:48:21.616297Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.616314Z 0 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
2022-02-10T06:48:21.616955Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.617005Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2022-02-10T06:48:21.682478Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.q6ChLS0FIM/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)
2022-02-10T06:48:21.747960Z 3 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751266Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751284Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751291Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751331Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751679Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751688Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751692Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751696Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751699Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751726Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751730Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751736Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751740Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751743Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751750Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751753Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751757Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751760Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751771Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751775Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751778Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751782Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751785Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751788Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751792Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751795Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751798Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751805Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751808Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751812Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751815Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751818Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751825Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751828Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751832Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751835Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751838Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751842Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751845Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2022-02-10T06:48:21.751974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-02-10T06:48:21.752015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220210  6:48:21
2022-02-10T06:48:21.752037Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-10T06:48:21.752203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220210  6:48:21
2022-02-10T06:48:23.180121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 36134591327
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181629Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181644Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181651Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181656Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181660Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2022-02-10T06:48:23.181788Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2022-02-10T06:48:23.182138Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When I start MySQL, this is what the logs say:

```
2022-02-10T07:00:47.819747Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-02-10T07:00:47.821725Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 8871 ...
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826117Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826150Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826411Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-10T07:00:47.826520Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-02-10T07:00:47.829890Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-02-10T07:00:47.900431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-10T07:00:47.916391Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-02-10T07:00:47.928336Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2022-02-10T07:00:47.928362Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 0 undo tablespaces made active
2022-02-10T07:00:47.928568Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-02-10T07:00:47.958351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-02-10T07:00:47.958418Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-02-10T07:00:47.988870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-02-10T07:00:47.989095Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: The parameter innodb_undo_logs is deprecated and may be removed in future releases. Please use innodb_rollback_segments instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-undo-logs.html
2022-02-10T07:00:47.989671Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 redo rollback segment(s) found. 1 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-02-10T07:00:47.989680Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-02-10T07:00:47.989974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-02-10T07:00:48.040194Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.37 started; log sequence number 36134591327
2022-02-10T07:00:48.040548Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.041907Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2022-02-10T07:00:48.041936Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.042370Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist
2022-02-10T07:00:48.042391Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.043734Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.043748Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.043753Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.043756Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.044304Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.044336Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.044406Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2022-02-10T07:00:48.044423Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2022-02-10T07:00:48.046215Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.046442Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.046460Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2022-02-10T07:00:48.046921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-10T07:00:48.050380Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.050401Z 0 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
2022-02-10T07:00:48.053135Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-02-10T07:00:48.053164Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2022-02-10T07:00:48.057666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220210  7:00:48
2022-02-10T07:00:48.060428Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-02-10T07:00:48.060602Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

*EDIT*

Also, I use some custom parameters (`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_undo_tablespaces = 3
innodb_undo_directory = /var/lib/mysql/undo
innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON
innodb_max_undo_log_size = 16M
innodb_undo_logs = 1
```

*Edit 2*

Last night I restarted the MySQL server in one of the three machines to see if this morning it would not crash like the last few days (as they seem to stop about 24 hours after being started).

Unfortunately, MySQL stopped again at about the same time.

I checked the available RAM in the machine a few minutes before the shutdown, I had about 1 GB available. It is usually the RAM that is available. PM2 consumes almost nothing.

I also reinstalled MySQL completely in another of the three machines (with the same configuration). And on this one, there is no crash so far.

*EDIT 3*

Thanks to Gerrit last comment, I found something interesting in `/var/log/dpkg.log`:

```
2022-02-11 06:08:17 startup packages remove
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status installed linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1
2022-02-11 06:08:17 remove linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1 <none>
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status half-configured linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status half-installed linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status config-files linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status config-files linux-modules-5.4.0-1063-aws:amd64 5.4.0-1063.66~18.04.1
2022-02-11 06:08:17 startup packages configure
2022-02-11 06:08:17 configure mysql-server-5.7:amd64 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 <none>
2022-02-11 06:08:17 status half-configured mysql-server-5.7:amd64 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

This happened at the same time as the MySQL server stopped.

How can I disable this "configure mysql-server-5.7" script or finish it manually to fix the issue?

Comment: It seems like the mysql database definition in innodb main datafile is out of sync with the situation in the data/mysql filesystem. Did a mysql upgrade happen on a busy system and got interrupted? See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Comment: @Gerrit, I don't know, it seems unlikely that this happened on all three servers. Do you think that a new reinstallation could solve the problem?

Comment: It is mainly the message about .frm that files that exist but cannot be found in innodb's data dictionary that spell trouble. Is there a /var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info file and what is its filetime? As there seems to be a disjoint between the tablespace dictionary and the filesystem, this probably is not related to the mysql executables. If you have a backup you could try that on one system to see if that starts right without these .frm messages.

Comment: Also this seems very low: 1 redo rollback segment(s) found. Did you store undo_logs somewhere else? Try setting innodb_rollback_segments to 128.

Comment: Do you have a  innodb_undo_directory setting? Because mysql only seems to find the rollback segment inside the main tablespace.

Comment: @Gerrit, I updated the post to share my custom configuration

Comment: innodb_undo_logs (alias of innodb_rollback_segments) is way, way too low. Even one transaction using both inserts and updates outside of temporary tables would fail. And with just 1, the truncate setting will never work either. Set it to 128 and be done with that.

Comment: How much RAM?  Which version of MySQL?  Is there a regular backup _of any kind_?

Comment: Version 5.7.37 became GA on 2022 01 18 - less than a month ago.  Maybe you have an edge case creating your unique problem.  innodb_buffer_pool_size is really needing only 1 G?  Rick and I would like to know how much RAM on the server?  I can see 5.7.37 in the error log at startup.

Comment: @RickJames, the amount of RAM available in the machine is 2 GB. And no, there is no backup of any kind. The only things that are running are the MySQL server and a PM2 instance.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, isn't 1GB enough for innodb_buffer_pool_size? I've been using this configuration for months now (let alone at first), and had no problems until recently. Yes, the version is 5.7.37

Comment: Suggest dropping `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `500M`; I don't know how much RAM PM2 consumes.

Comment: Three months ago, 5.7.37 was not available.  I would have to suspect something related to 5.7.37 upgrade your version did not finish successfully.  Innodb_buffer_pool_size of 1G is enough. as Rick James suggested, drop it to 500M and you might survive on your 2G server.

Comment: @RickJames, I don't think it's related to RAM, as there is usually about 1GB available when I check regularly. PM2 consumes almost nothing at all.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I usually do the Ubuntu updates with the MySQL server on, which is a very bad idea! Also, transactions are constantly being performed on the MySQL server. So it's possible that the last update happened at the wrong time.

Comment: Is the unattended upgrades trying to finish the upgrade each time again in the morning? Look in the files /var/log/unattended-upgrades and in /var/log/dpkg.log

Comment: Thank you @Gerrit, I updated the post. Apparently some "configure mysql-server-5.7" script is causing the shutdown

Comment: You are having trouble with exactly those tables in the mysql database itself that are stored on innodb. Probably setting innodb_undo_logs = 1 proved to be disastrous on upgrade. Stopping mysql server and doing `apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.7` after you let that setting default or put it on 128 should fix it.

Comment: @Gerrit, thank you. Apparently it worked. You may want to add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

When a service shuts down on Ubuntu server unexpectedly a possible cause is unattended-upgrades, which runs some time in the early morning. Activity of this system can be seen in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/` files and `/var/log/dkpg.log`.

If such an upgrade gets stuck, it will try again in the next round of unattended-upgrades or on any apt upgrade action.

Having mysql running when the upgrade comes, is not harmful in itself, because the upgrade script will stop the service and run it in isolation. However the local service settings that you made for mysql can still have an impact on that upgrade run.

You can check the package status with `dpkg -l mysql-server-5.7`

In this case mysql startup messages indicated that the internal state of the innodb dictionary of tables differed from the situation seen on disk. Messages like: `Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue. mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist` indicate that the `mysql` system database was affected. This normally changes only on an upgrade of mysql.

Also there was a message on startup:`1 redo rollback segment(s) found`

This is not normal, with default settings for rollback segments it will be 96. It can be set with `innodb_rollback_segments` or its alias `innodb_undo_logs`. This parameter has disappeared altogether in newer versions of mysql. The purpose of rollback segments is to store data that is under alteration by updates and inserts inside sql transactions on the innodb engine and to provide for the ACIDness of transactions. For temporary tables there is a separate 32 rollback segments without redo. Each updating transaction and each inserting transaction needs a separate rollback segment. So even one transaction can need 2 rollback segments. Now if you have only one rollback segment, the transaction can never run to completion. Such a situation can go unnoticed for a time because lots of simple code never uses transactions except for the implicit ones and usually one statement does not update and insert at the same time. But sooner or later you will run into a blocking situation like this, where the upgrade script got stuck. Also your undo tablespaces will grow indefinitely because without a rollback segment in reserve the truncate will never run.

Remove the customized setting for rollback segments and reinstall the service with `apt install -reinstall mysql-server-5.7` or try to run the configure script manually with `dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.7`.